# Confirmation message Spring shell

Tags: spring-shell

Is there an way for a spring-shell command to first ask for a confirmation message. For example

> > command
>
> Do you want to proceed [y/n]
>
> > y
>
> executing command

I did some research on internet but I don't find example of this type of command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using `jline.console.ConsoleReader` (which spring-shell currently uses as well) for this, so the code looks something like:

```
public static boolean askYesNo(String question) {
    while (true) {
        String backup = ask(String.format("%s (y/n): ", question));
        if ("y".equals(backup)) {
            return true;
        }
        if ("n".equals(backup)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

public static String ask(String question) {
    question = "\n" + question + " > ";

    try {
        ConsoleReader consolereader = new ConsoleReader();
        return consolereader.readLine(question);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: depending on what shell environment you launched from intially, this can blow up...

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49770449/select-from-a-small-amount-of-options-in-spring-shell

Answer (score 0):

You can read from `System.in` and continue/abort execution of your command as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

```
 try {

      System.out.println("** Press 'y' to delete  OR  'n' to cancel operation **");

        ConsoleReader consolereader = new ConsoleReader();


        int readCharacter = consolereader.readCharacter('y','n');//just can read 'y' and 'n' char. y=121 , n=110


        System.out.println(readCharacter);

       if (readCharacter == 121) {
          // do delete  operation
        } else if (readCharacter == 110) {
          // do cancel operation
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

### ** Press 'y' to delete  OR  'n' to cancel operation **

### 121